# Mysql Trigger - Update table when insert another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables:

Import Table:

```
import_id  | import_date
-------------------------
   1       | 2019/07/29
   2       | 2019/07/28
```

ImportItem Table:

```
import_id    |  product_id |  quantity
-------------------------------------
    1        |     1       |   50
    1        |     2       |   60
    1        |     3       |   20
```

Product Table:

```
product_id   |  quantity   
---------------------------
    1        |     10       
    2        |     5       
    3        |     15
```

I want to create a trigger update quantity in product table when insert ImportItem table.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you get an error? If yes, please add that message and add, when you get the message (e.g when you insert or when you try to create the trigger). Or isn't it working/does it something unexpected? Then describe that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a trigger in your table **import_item** that will update your table **product** after each **import_item** `INSERT` you can do this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
ON import_item FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product SET quantity = NEW.quantity WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
END
```

Here is some documentation about the trigger key words `NEW` and `OLD` : [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

When you are in a `BEFORE/AFTER INSERT` trigger, you can use `NEW.field` to get the value of the new field you just inserted.

Now if you are in a `BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE` trigger, you can use `NEW.field` to get the value of the field AFTER the update and `OLD.value` to get the value of the field BEFORE the update.

And the last, if you are in a `BEFORE/AFTER DELETE` trigger , you can use `OLD.field` to get the value fo the field before the delete.

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Great. That's what I need. Thank you very much!